# How to create an XmlMappingSource during runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-sql

(Follow-Up-Question to [How to change LINQ O/R-M table name/source during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582221/how-to-change-linq-o-r-m-table-name-source-during-runtime))

I need to change the table source of a LINQ 2 SQL O/R-Mapper table during runtime. To achieve this, I need to create an [XmlMappingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386907.aspx). On command line, I could use SqlMetal to create this mapping file, but I would like to create the mapping file during runtime in memory.
The XmlMappingSource is a simple xml file, looking something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Database Name="MyDatabase" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/linqtosql/mapping/2007">
  <Table Name="dbo.MyFirstTable" Member="MyFirstTable">
    <Type Name="MyFirstTable">
      <Column Name="ID" Member="ID" Storage="_ID" DbType="UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsDbGenerated="true" AutoSync="OnInsert" />
      <Association Name="WaStaArtArtikel_WaVerPreisanfragen" Member="WaStaArtArtikel" Storage="_WaStaArtArtikel" ThisKey="ArtikelID" OtherKey="ID" IsForeignKey="true" />
    </Type>
  </Table>
  <Table Name="dbo.MySecondTable" Member="MySecondTable">
    <Type Name="MySecondTable">
      <Column Name="ID" Member="ID" Storage="_ID" DbType="UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsDbGenerated="true" AutoSync="OnInsert" />
      <Column Name="FirstTableID" Member="FirstTableID" Storage="_FirstTableID" DbType="UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL" />
      <Association Name="MySecondTable_MyFirstTable" Member="MyFirstTable" Storage="_MyFirstTable" ThisKey="FirstTableID" OtherKey="ID" IsForeignKey="true" />
    </Type>
  </Table>
</Database>
```

This should be possible to create using reflection, for example I can get the database name from a data context like this:

```
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Xml.Linq;

XDocument mapWriter = new XDocument();
DatabaseAttribute[] catx = (DatabaseAttribute[])typeof(WcfInterface.WaDataClassesDataContext).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DatabaseAttribute), false);
XElement xDatabase = new XElement("Database");
xDatabase.Add(new XAttribute("Name", catx[0].Name));
mapWriter.Add(xDatabase);
```

My problem: I can't find good documentation of the mapping, so extracting the necessary information is quite error-prone - maybe someone can point me to good docs of the mapping, or, even better, to a code example how to create the mapping file?

Comment: Suggest you say LINQ to SQL explicitly at the start of this to avoid confusion with LINQ to Entities (which is much more of an ORM than LINQ to SQL -- much richer mapping capability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using LINQ to Entities, the mapping formats for LINQ to Entities are documented.

Comment: Actually, I was not really aware of L2E as a replacement for L2S.
So, in L2E it is possible to just change the mapping during runtime?

Comment: I would not consider L2E as a /replacement/, but as the "big brother". L2S is simple, but limited; L2E is much more functional but harder to use.

Comment: So, how would I change the table name in L2E than?

Comment: I know you /can/ swap mappings, just not /how/. Well until I have sometime available to really dig into L2E.

Answer (score 1):

Use Damien Guard's Open Source T4 templates. They do everything SQLMetal can do and more, and you'll have the full T4 engine behind you.

Comment: Uhm, maybe you can explain how this would help me for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just had same problem, also I had no option to change project as its too late to do this.

I needed to update database name in mapping file in my solution.
This solution works.

My database mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Database Name="DatabaseName" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/linqtosql/mapping/2007">
  <Table Name="dbo.tblDictionary" Member="TblDictionary">
    <Type Name="TblDictionary">
      <Column Name="lngRecordID" Member="LngRecordID" Storage="_LngRecordID" DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsDbGenerated="true" AutoSync="OnInsert" />
      <Column Name="txtWord" Member="TxtWord" Storage="_TxtWord" DbType="VarChar(50) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
    </Type>
  </Table>
</Database>
```

and finally the code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        // to get embeded file name you have to add namespace of the application
        const string embeddedFilename = "ConsoleApplication3.FrostOrangeMappings.xml";
        // load file into stream
        var embeddedStream = GetEmbeddedFile(embeddedFilename);
        // process stream
        ProcessStreamToXmlMappingSource(embeddedStream);
        Console.ReadKey();


    }

    private static void ProcessStreamToXmlMappingSource(Stream stream)
    {

        const string newDatabaseName = "pavsDatabaseName";      

        var mappingFile = new XmlDocument();
        mappingFile.Load(stream);
        stream.Close();


        // populate collection of attribues
        XmlAttributeCollection collection = mappingFile.DocumentElement.Attributes;

        var attribute = collection["Name"];
        if(attribute==null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to find Name attribute in xml definition");
        }

        // set new database name definition
        collection["Name"].Value = newDatabaseName;

        //display xml to  user
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
          using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
          {
              mappingFile.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
              xmlTextWriter.Flush();
              stringWriter.GetStringBuilder();
          }
        Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.ToString());

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads file into stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Stream GetEmbeddedFile(string fileName)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fileName);

        if (stream == null)
            throw new Exception("Could not locate embedded resource '" + fileName + "' in assembly");

        return stream;
    }`
```