# How do I switch the table that is queried with linq-to-sql

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

We have two tables with the same set of columns; depending on the “type” of object the value is stored in one of the two tables.  I wish to use common code to access these two tables.

If I was using “raw sql” I could just use String.Format() to change the table name.

(Likewise for updates etc)

---

The two separate tables are needed as the data access patterns are very different for the *common* queries on the two tables and therefore different indexes are needed.    “Views” and “instead of triggers” etc to make the tables look like a single table are not liked here.   A lot of our customers use low end version of SqlServer so we cannot use partition tables.

---

Update:

Part of the issue I have is that I have lots of methods like

```
IQueryable<Event> AddFlexibleFieldsFilter(
   FlexibleFields flexibleFields, 
   IQueryable<Event> qry, 
   IQueryable<EventFlexibleField> fields
   )
```

And using subclass or interfaces don’t play well with generic types (we are still on .net 3.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, there's no easy way. It's possible to create two XML mappings and then load the appropriate mapping via an explicit [DataContext constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534562.aspx) at runtime. Related links:

- [How to change LINQ O/R-M table name/source during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582221/how-to-change-linq-o-r-m-table-name-source-during-runtime)
- http://guy.dotnet-expertise.com/PermaLink,guid,789dd70b-73b9-4216-a479-77e19d403e38.aspx

This will certainly dirty-up your Linq-to-Sql logic as you'll need to determine which type you're working with before you create your DataContext.

I might consider two data access classes mapped to either table with a master class that fetches its data from the appropriate source given a type. Then a developer can use the master class without worrying about where the data is coming from.

Comment: Thanks, I don't using a master class will work well, please see my edit to the question.